# Casting the apps content

Tags: android, casting, iptv

I've done an iptv app. I'm wondering of there is a way to cast the screen inside the app to other devices. Does it mean that I have to design an app to tvs too?

I've been searching on github, but I wonder if you have a favorite or if it is possible to code in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Casting requires a sender (e.g. the tablet or phone) and a receiver (e.g. a TV).

You need to have either an app or functionality in an app on both the sender and the receiver.

However, Chrome cast as an example also have some basic general receiver capability built in.

There is a getting started guide for Chrome cast here:

- https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers

and a some example open source example Android sender apps here:

- https://github.com/googlecast